# How to specify both IPv6 and v4 in Security Groups in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I tried to create a security group like:

```
  WebTierSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - Description: Allow HTTP
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          CidrIpv6: ::/0
```

But CloudFormation complains I cannot have both `CidrIp` and `CidrIpv6`. How do I resolve this? I thought I can have both via AWS console?

> Both CidrIp and CidrIpv6 cannot be specified

Comment: Have you enabled IPv6 on creation of VPC?

Comment: @KumareshBabu there is no such option in CloudFormation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html

Answer (score 8):

The SecurityGroupIngress (and also SecurityGroupEgress) property of resource is of type list/array. Your must supply a list of Resources, or list of rules to be applied to security group. Each rule must have a CidrIp OR a CidrIpv6, not both the same time. When you need to allow the two protocols you must apply two different rules: Change you template like below:

```
  WebTierSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - Description: Allow HTTP
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - Description: Allow HTTP
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          CidrIpv6: ::/0
```