# Cloudformation ipv4 and ipv6 egress

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I would like to add an alltraffic ipv4 and alltraffic ipv6 outbound rule to my security group. However, Cloudformation keeps building just the ipv6 when i defined both.

I started with the following code:

```
    SecurityGroupEgressAllTrafficipv4:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress'
      Properties:
        Description: "Allow all outbound traffic by default"
        GroupId: !Ref "SecurityGroup"
        CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"        
        IpProtocol: "-1"

    SecurityGroupEgressAllTrafficipv6:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress'
      Properties:
        Description: "Allow all outbound traffic by default"
        GroupId: !Ref "SecurityGroup"
        CidrIpv6: "::/0"        
        IpProtocol: "-1"
```

Since it was only building ipv6, I found this post as reference: [How to specify both IPv6 and v4 in Security Groups in CloudFormation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515805/how-to-specify-both-ipv6-and-v4-in-security-groups-in-cloudformation/51886750). I tried the format that the commenter posted and was receiving an error: *Error: Template format error: Any Properties member must be an object.*

```
    SecurityGroupEgressAllTraffic:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress'
      Properties:
        - Description: "Allow all outbound traffic by default"
          GroupId: !Ref "SecurityGroup"
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"        
          IpProtocol: "-1"
        - Description: "Allow all outbound traffic by default"
          GroupId: !Ref "SecurityGroup"
          CidrIpv6: "::/0"        
          IpProtocol: "-1"
```

Has anyone attempted this with success? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 GroupId: !Ref "SecurityGroup"
```

it should be:

```
 GroupId: !GetAtt SecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Comment: I tried updating the GroupId property for egress rules and received an error:

E1012 Ref SecurityGroup.GroupId not found as a resource or parameter

I was able to create the egress rule with just  GroupId: !Ref "SecurityGroup". It does not appear the issue is with the reference. For some reason when I can only create one alltraffic ipv* rule. When I add two, only the ipv6 alltraffic rule gets created.

Comment: Additionally, I have an ALLTCP egress rule defined and that's being built fine...The issue is somehow related to ALLTRAFFIC?

Comment: @TechTraffic I would suggest providing full template and errors. From what you write, everything is fine and there are no issues with your short snippet of code.

Comment: I apologize my initial read of the code was incorrect. When I modified the code, I used !Ref SecurityGroup.GroupId. I did not catch the !GetAtt difference. When I changed it to !GetAtt, this did work. Thank you.